# Rails 3.1 asset pipeline CSS manifest.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

So I have app/stylesheets/screen.css.sass

On production the path becomes something /assets/screen-md5hash.css

The file is getting served, however it does not appear in manifest.yml, nor does it appear in the public/assets folder (therefore I assume it gets served by Rails, not Apache).

Why is it not there?

Comment: Are the other assets in manifest.yml and in public ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct - the file is being served by Sprockets.

This suggests a couple of issues with your pipeline config settings.

The first is that you may still have

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

in `production.rb`.

It should be false. If it is true then any assets that are not precompiled (and in the public directory) are served by Sprockets.

The second is that if you want to reference any js or css file that is NOT named `application`, then you have to add that file to the precompile array for it to be precompiled for production.

The fact that it is missing from the manifest suggests that it was not precompiled.

You should add this in `application.rb`:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['screen.css']
```

If this is an upgraded app, can I suggest you check all your pipeline config setting against the [last section of the pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#upgrading-from-old-versions-of-rails).